# Why is TextView not aligned as coded?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

The text view tv_title is always displayed above the activity even though when I've set bottom margin 0dp.

Here is the screenshot:

[image: xml layout screenshot]

Also when bottom margin is 10 dp, the text view goes further up:

[image: xml layout screenshot]

Comment: edit you question with the code

Comment: But I need to shows the image also of design view, so I uploaded them

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using noactionbar theme so it does't appear . but if you want using without actionbar than just use :

android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"

this may help.

or Use :

remove android:layout_above="@+id/tv_desc" from tv_title textview. and add android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title" in tv_desc textview will help you.

Comment: the problem is with text view not actionbar

Comment: ok than remove android:layout_above="@+id/tv_desc"  from tv_title textview. and add         android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title" in tv_desc textview will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood the problem, since the question isn't clear (I don't understand what's the outcome you want) and you didn't add your whole xml code.

`tv_title` and `tv_desc` have 120dp space between them because `tv_desc` has `marginTop 120dp`. When you add `marginBottom = 10dp` to `tv_title`, the space equals to 130dp.

In `RelativeLayout`, if you want to display `tv_title` beneath `tv_desc`, add `layout_below` field to `tv_title`.

And it would be better for you to see some `RelativeLayout` examples.